# Encryption of Strings works, encryption of byte[] array type does not work

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, aes

I am using the following [LINK](http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html)  for encryption and tried it with Strings and it worked. However, since I am dealing with images,  I needed the encryption/decryption process to happen with byte arrays. So I modified the code in that link to the following:

```
public class AESencrp {

    private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = 
    new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };

    public static byte[] encrypt(byte[] Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data);
        //String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encVal;
    }

    public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(encryptedData);
        return decValue;
    }

    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
    }
```

and the checker class is:

```
public class Checker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        byte[] array = new byte[]{127,-128,0};
        byte[] arrayEnc = AESencrp.encrypt(array);
        byte[] arrayDec = AESencrp.decrypt(arrayEnc);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + array);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + arrayEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + arrayDec);
    }
}
```

However my output is:

```
Plain Text : [B@1b10d42
Encrypted Text : [B@dd87b2
Decrypted Text : [B@1f7d134
```

So the decrypted text is not the same as plain text. What should I do to fix this knowing that I tried the example in the original link and it worked with Strings?

Comment: You actually don't know if the decrypted output is right or not - you're printing object addresses, not contents. Compare the contents of the arrays.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're seeing is the result of the array's toString() method. It's not the content of the byte array. Use `java.util.Arrays.toString(array)` to display the content of the arrays.

`[B` is the type (array of bytes), and `1b10d42` is the hashCode of the array.

Comment: Thank you :) it worked. I will accept your. I still have one question do you think I can run this code on android without any problems? And If i am transforming the images to byte array, then encrypted, receive, decrypt and transform to image back again, would there be any problem?

Comment: I've never done anything on Android, but if the API is supported, I don't see why it wouldn't work. If the images are large, avoid loading the whole byte array in memory to encrypt it. Read it by chunks, and send the chunks to a CipherOutputStream.

Comment: What can i do if i don't know the file of the image that i am going to receive? I m facing the same error it seems because i am setting the size of the byte array manually , for example byte[] array = new byte[60000] where the image received should be around 60 kb.

Comment: You don't need to initialize any byte array, since the doFinal method of the Cipher does it for you, and returns the decrypted byte array.

Answer (score 8):

> However my output is:
>
> ```
> Plain Text : [B@1b10d42
> Encrypted Text : [B@dd87b2
> Decrypted Text : [B@1f7d134
> ```

That's because you're printing out the result of calling `toString()` on a byte array. That's not going to show you anything useful, other than a suggestion of reference identity.

You should either just compare the plaintext data with the decrypted data byte for byte (which you can do with [`Arrays.equals(byte[], byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#equals%28byte%5B%5D,%20byte%5B%5D%29)), or if you really want to display the contents, print out the hex or base64 representation. `[Arrays.toString(byte\[\])][2]` will give you *a* representation, but hex would probably be easier to read. There are loads of hex formatting classes in third-party libraries, or you could find a method on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you Jon yes you are totally right, can u pls help me with the question that i posted above?

Comment: @Adroidist: It's not clear what you mean by "if I don't know the file of the image" - that doesn't make sense. If you're talking about the *size*, you should basically treat it as a stream - keep reading a block, encrypting it, reading the next block etc until you run out of data. Ditto for decrypting.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's too late but I'm sharing my answer. Here I have used your code with some modification. Try below checker class to encrypt and decrypt a byte array.

Checker class:

```
public class Checker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        byte[] array = "going to encrypt".getBytes();
        byte[] arrayEnc = AESencrp.encrypt(array);
        byte[] arrayDec = AESencrp.decrypt(arrayEnc);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + array);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + arrayEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + new String(arrayDec));
    }
}
```