# Android - Jave Server AES encryption Not working - Different keys

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

I am trying to encrypt images on android, send them to the server so that it process them. The server has to decrypt  the received message. I already posted the code in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562908/encryption-of-strings-works-encryption-of-byte-array-type-does-not-work/)

I have called the encrypt function on the Android side and the decrypt function the java server side (image is sent via TCP).

However, I am receiving the error:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
```

I output the key on android and got:

```
 javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@652
```

whereas on the Java server (developped using Netbeans) I got:

```
javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@148dd
```

I thought that the padding is different so I used

```
AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
```

instead of 
    AES

but the Java server output an error:

```
should use AES.
```

How can i solve this issue?

For send on android side:

```
 public void send(Bitmap mRgbImage1_array, int port_number)
        throws IOException {

socket = new Socket("192.168.0.107", port_number);
boolean encrypt = HomeScreen.checkbox2.isChecked();
ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

mRgbImage1_array.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
InputStream photoStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(photoStream);
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[photoStream.available()];
bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
photoStream.close();

if(encrypt)
   {
 try {
byte[] dst = Security.encrypt(mybytearray);
mybytearray = new byte[10000];
for(int i=0; i<dst.length;i++)
{
     mybytearray[i] = dst[i];   
}

 } catch (Exception e1) {
    /// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

}
    os = socket.getOutputStream();
    os.write(mybytearray);
            os.flush();
    os.close();
if (os != null)
{
try {
os.close();
    } 

    catch (IOException e) 
       {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
 }

}
```

For receive on Java server side:

```
    public static void receive(int port_number) {
    boolean received = false;

    Socket socket = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    int bytesRead;
    int current = 0;

    BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        if (serverSocket == null) {
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port_number);
        }
        System.out.println("Listening :" + port_number);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (!received) {
        try {
            socket = serverSocket.accept();
            InetAddress ip = socket.getInetAddress();
            String[] ip1 = ip.toString().split("/");
            ip2 = ip1[1];
            System.out.println("ip is " + ip2);
            byte[] mybytearray = new byte[10000000];
            is = socket.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fos = new    FileOutputStream("source-image.jpeg");
            bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
           current = bytesRead;
            do {
                bytesRead =
                        is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length - current));
                if (bytesRead >= 0) {
                    current += bytesRead;
                }

            } while (bytesRead > -1);
if(Networker.should_encrypt)
            {
         try {
     mybytearray = Security1.decrypt(mybytearray);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            /// TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
            bos.write(mybytearray, 0, current);
            bos.flush();
            bos.close();

            received = true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyServer1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (is != null) {
                try {
                    is.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
   }
```

Comment: The values you're printing out are simply showing that they're `SecretKeySpec` objects, along with the hash code. There's no information about the *content* of the key in there. You'll have to post the code - both encryption and decryption, sending and receiving. There are various things you could be doing wrong.

Comment: @Jon, the code of encrypt and decrypt is posted in the link i mentioned in the question. Copy paste on android and on java server

Comment: @Adrodist: And the code for sending and receiving?

Comment: @Adriodist: Any chance you could format it so it's actually readable? The indentation is all over the place.

Comment: @Adriodist: Actually, I think I've spotted the problem anyway...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the problem:

```
mybytearray = Security1.decrypt(mybytearray);
```

That's *always* going to decrypt 10000000 bytes, even if you've only actually *written* a small amount of data. You should change your `decrypt` method to say how much data to decrypt, then call `doFinal(byte[], int, int)`.

I'd also suggest trying to handle the encryption/decryption in a streaming manner rather than preallocating 10MB (which is going to be wasteful in most cases, and could be too short in others), but that's a larger change.

Additionally, this is a bad idea in the encrypting code:

```
byte[] mybytearray = new byte[photoStream.available()];
bis.read(mybytearray, 0, mybytearray.length);
photoStream.close();
```

You're *assuming* that the amount available to start with is the whole file. That may not be the case. You should generally loop round, reading from the file stream and writing to an encrypting stream. Oh, and the `close()` call should be in a finally block.

If you *really* want to do all the encryption/decryption in one call, you can loop round reading from the file or network stream and writing into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`, so that you don't need to hard-code the size or assume it from `available()`. Then use `ByteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()` to get a byte array of the right size. (That involves an extra copy, admittedly.)

Comment: But I do not know the size of the image file beforehand + encryption is an option for the user so it the file is not always encrypted. If I want to use ByteArrayOutputStream how should i start?

Comment: @Jon is right, you can't read a byte array input stream that way. Available is the amount of data available right now in a stream, not the total amount of data to come. Use a loop to read the InputStream from the photoStream, then copy every byte read in a buffer if you want or in a file.

Comment: while( (byteReadCount = bis.read( buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1 ) {
 //copy buffer bytes somewhere for encryption, later 
 bos.write( buffer, 0, byteReadCount );
}

Comment: i should modify this on the android side ? isn't the problem on the server side since it is the one decrypting. sorry for my silly questions i m not an expert

Comment: @Adroidist: Both sides have incorrect code around the streaming, as I've explained in my answer: the code reading the file is assuming that everything is available in one go, and the code decrypting it is assuming that the *whole* 10MB buffer contains encrypted data.

Comment: Actually, I would seriously make sure you read more on stream handling in Java Andoidist, because I can easily spot a few more mistakes (e.g. with regard to the `bis` in your android code, `read()` should be in a loop and you should `close()` the stream)